# Java - Implementing a thread-safety set method with returning the new value

Tags: java, thread-safety, atomic

I am trying to implement a set method for an AtomicInteger and return the new value. Unfortunately, it comes to race conditions. I think it is because the two statements `this.counter.set(newValue);` and `return this.counter.get();` are not Atomic if I let them run together. I also tried to use a synchronized block, but it did not help either. Do you know how I can set a new Value and return the value in an atomic method? For reasons, I **can't** change the method signature.

Here is the Class where the set method should be:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import util.Incrementer;

public class AtomicIncrementer implements Incrementer {

    private AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
    private int startValue;

    public AtomicIncrementer(int startValue) {
        this.startValue = startValue;
        this.counter.set(startValue);
    }

    @Override
    public int setValue(int newValue) {
        // TODO: implement, do not change method the signature!
        synchronized (this.counter) {
            this.counter.set(newValue);
            return this.counter.get();
        }

    }


}
```

I am running this test:

```
package incrementer;

import impl.AtomicIncrementer;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

public class TestAtomicIncrementer {

    private final int defaultThreadPoolSize = 8;
    private final int defaultThreadCount = 24;

    @Test
    void testSetValue() {
        int newValue = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
        AtomicIncrementer inc = new AtomicIncrementer(0);
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(defaultThreadPoolSize);
        for(int i = 0; i < defaultThreadCount; i++) {
            executor.submit(() -> {
                for(int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
                    inc.increment();
                }
                return null;
            });
        }
        try {
            assertEquals(newValue, executor.submit(() -> inc.setValue(newValue)).get());
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        try {
            executor.shutdown();
            assertTrue(executor.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        inc.setValue(newValue);
        assertEquals(newValue, inc.getValue());
    }

    private List<Future<Integer>> executeOperation(Callable<Integer> op, AtomicIncrementer inc, int threadCount, int threadPoolSize) {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadPoolSize);
        List<Callable<Integer>> ops = new ArrayList<>(threadCount);
        for(int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++) {
            ops.add(op);
        }
        try {
            return executor.invokeAll(ops);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Sometimes the test success and sometimes not, which seems like a race condition Problem for me.

What do you think?

Comment: How about `counter.set(newValue); return newValue;`? I have no idea what use your class is.

Comment: Why is `counter` `static`?

Comment: Counter has not to be static (changed it). But it still does not work.

Comment: @kayaman Yes this can be a solution. But I think there should be another solution.

Comment: Because this is an interview question and you don't think they expect such a stupid answer to it?

Comment: @Kayamn haha No but I'm not sure if there can be problems if methods call the set functions and always get back the newValue. What if another thread sets a different value between this.counter.set(newValue); and return newValue;? The calling function will still get back the newValue, even the value has changed.

Comment: Exactly. You seem to be confused about your requirements. I'll let you think about it for a while.

Comment: @kayaman unfortunately the requirements are not more clear now. I just want to know if there is another way to do it :)

Comment: Re, "...implement a set method for an AtomicInteger and return the new value." That is an impossible requirement. You can write a method, `set(x)` that sets the value to `x` and returns `x`, but you _cannot_ write a method that guarantees that the value still will be `x` by the time the call returns. If the caller needs the value to not change, then that's the caller's problem. It has to be solved at the caller's level. It can't be solved inside the `set(x)` method.

Comment: The test calls `inc.increment();`, where is that implemented? And what is failing? There are too many inconsistencies in your question.

Comment: @kayaman Thank you for your effort. Perhaps my question did not make it clear. I just want to know if there is a way to write a set() method with a retrun and threadsafty.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Thanks, I guess then I will try it with sets the value to x and returns x like Kayaman explained.

Comment: Yes it's possible with a mutex. It's just unnecessary for the silly logic.

Comment: If you are supposed to return the new value then simply `return newValue;`.  The additional load accomplishes nothing.  Yes, it is possible that another thread stored to the value immediately after your `counter.set()`, but in your version, such a store could also happen immediately after your `counter.get()`.  So either way the value returned to the caller may be stale by the time it actually gets used.  For this reason, "return the new value" is a useless design.  Returning the *old* value would actually be useful in some cases, though.

Comment: This would be a good time to learn about [TOCTOU bugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use), since any code that thinks it wants "the new value" probably contains such a bug.